# Deploy war file on apache tomcat upon creation

Tags: java, linux, maven, jsp, tomcat

### I'm not well experienced in java.

I build a UI using JSP for my servlets to get input data from users. Everytime I want to see the UI and how the Servlets are performing I have to  do all thses steps over and over again,

1. create the `war` file by `mvn clean install`
2. Copy war file to Webapps folder
3. restart apache tomcat
4. View the result using the url

I want to know if there is a command that i can use to rerun apache tomcat with the `war` file im building at once, So that i only have to refresh the webpage to see the result. Or any method that is easier than above.

I use Intellij Idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most  IDEs (e.g. Eclipse for Java EE) will allow you to link the server within, and publish with a button press.

Comment: Unfortunately i use Intellij Idea. Do you know if it can do the same?

Comment: Never used it but should be a standard. Give a little google search on "link server on intellij"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition** does not support **J2EE**, but you can also achieve this in the following two ways. For full support of tomcat, you can buy **IntelliJ IDEA Enterpries Edition**.

**Use `maven-compiler-plugin`**
1) Add this plugin to your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <finalName>mvn-webapp</finalName>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.5.1</version>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
```

2) Then run this command:

```
mvn tomcat:run
```

**Or Install `Tomcat Runner Plugin`**

Refer to [this link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8266-tomcat-runner-plugin-for-intellij) for usage of this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

**May be this will help you to deploy the war file on server**
[image: May be this will help you to deploy the war file on server]

Comment: Thanks, but I can already do that process. I want to find a method to do it using a command or a plugin.